# Is there a way to merge data in a jsonb column in Rails in one go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb

I have a field in a table called email_preferences with some default values. Now I have to add a custom field to this object.

One way to do this is to go through all the records and manually updating each record like below:-

```rb
User.find_each do |user|
user.email_preferences['september_email'] = true
user.save
end
```

This is a very inefficient way of updating an existing jsonb field if there are a lot of values. Is there is something similar to the ActiveRecord `update_all` but for merging new data into the jsonb field and which does not require more than one call to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can also use the `||` operator to concatenate values to an existing jsonb object as demonstrated below:-

```rb
json_value = {september_email: true}.to_json

User.update_all("email_preferences = email_preferences || '#{json_value}'::jsonb")
```

More information about Postgresql operators and functions can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `JSONB_SET` pg function: `User.update_all "email_preferences = JSONB_SET(email_preferences, '{september_email}', 'true', true)"`